# Sonarqube webhook not valid with Jenkins Localhost

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, pipeline, webhooks

Im testing using a Sonarqube Server Community EditionVersion 8.4.1 (build 35646) and Jenkins Server 2.235.5. Both are in the same machine.

Im trying to implement Sonarqube functionalities in my Jenkins Pipeline following some tutorials.

This is the Pipeline Stage/Step where I have defined the Sonarqube implementation:

[image]

When I want to define a webhook in Sonarqube, appears me this message:

[image]

I already try to update windows host file with another name, but no working :(

Comment: You need to use domain name or IP of your server in url. Every time when I have created the webhook I have given the domain name of sonarqube server.

Answer (score 7):

You can change this behavior in the global configuration: Administration › General Settings > Security, setting "Enable local webhooks validation” to false.